# Getting Segmentation fault from printf

Tags: c, null

So basically i wrote 2 functions, to set a min and max number from input_array, in which both i would like to implement a code to return "-1" when NULL is called instead of input_array.
The code looks like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int array_min(const int input_array[], const int array_size);
int array_max(const int input_array[], const int array_size);
int main(){
        int input_array[]={1,12,3,43,5};
        printf("%d\n", array_min(input_array, 5));
        printf("%d\n", array_max(input_array, 5));
        printf("%d\n", array_max(NULL, 5));
}
int array_min(const int input_array[], const int array_size){
        int min = input_array[0];
        for(int i=1; i<array_size; i++){
                if( input_array[i] < min){
                        min = input_array[i];
                }
        }
        return min;
}
int array_max(const int input_array[], const int array_size){
        int max = input_array[0];
        for(int a=1; a<array_size; a++){
                if(input_array == NULL){
                        return -1;
                }
                else{
                        if(input_array[a]>max){
                                max = input_array[a];
                        }
                }
        }
        return max;
}
```

I tried to set max to -1 also but the result was the same, the program got compiled, but instead of the desired output of -1 it was "Segmentation fault".
What would be the best way to implement it to both the min and max functions?

Comment: Add the `NULL` checks before dereferencing.

Comment: How do you expect this te be handled `printf("%d\n", array_max(NULL, 5));` inside `array_max`

Comment: It is not in your `printf` calls. Instead it happends before `printf` is called during evaluation of th eparameters. `input_array[0];` This dereferences a `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, before checking for incoming `NULL`, you're dereferencing the pointer

```
 int max = input_array[0];
```

do that after your have validated the input.